# Akka HTTP shuts down prematurely in a docker container

Tags: scala, docker, akka-stream, akka-http

I have a simple Akka HTTP server running locally on port 8080. It works perfectly and displays the following message:

```
Started server at 127.0.0.1:8080, press enter to kill server
```

I am using `sbt-assembly` to create the .jar file. It lives under `target/scala-2.12/my-app-assembly-0.1.jar`

Then, I create a simple `Dockerfile` like:

```
FROM openjdk:8u131
ADD target/scala-2.12/my-app-assembly-0.1.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
CMD ["-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions", "-XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap", "-XX:MaxRAMFraction=1", "-XshowSettings:vm"]
```

Build the docker image:

```
docker build -t {my namespace}/my-app .
```

And run it:

```
docker run {my namespace}/my-app
```

Now, it also displays:

```
Started server at 127.0.0.1:8080, press enter to kill server
```

But immediately after that, it throws these errors and shutdowns:

```
...
[DEBUG] [10/08/2017 23:18:15.056] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7] [akka://default/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/0] Monitored actor [Actor[akka://default/user/StreamSupervisor-0/$$a#1560882800]] terminated
[DEBUG] [10/08/2017 23:18:15.060] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] [akka://default/system/IO-TCP/selectors/$a/0] Closing serverSocketChannel after being stopped
[DEBUG] [10/08/2017 23:18:15.067] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [EventStream] shutting down: StandardOutLogger started
```

Any ideas why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default Docker closes standard input which may impact your app due to it's prompt about user input: `press enter to kill server`.

[Run the container with the `-i` option to keep stdin open](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#foreground).

```
docker run -i {my namespace}/my-app
```

Normally daemon or server processes shouldn't require this.